# Manage idle time in an API request from an AWS Lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, chatbot

I'm trying to build a chatbot on AWS Lambda.

However, 90% of my Lambda duration is lost in requests wait time.

For each interaction a user has with my chatbot, I send approximately 3 requests (1 to Dialogflow and 2 to Messenger). I have to wait until those requests are completed because:

- for Dialogflow, I need the answer
- for Messenger, I need to make sure the previous message has been sent before sending the next one

Requests take approximately `400ms` so for every API call to my Lambda function, I "lose" most of my duration time waiting...

[image: aws request duration]

Do you have any hints about how I can avoid waiting 4000ms each time ?
Maybe I should move to a more common ec2 instance.

I was first really interested in stateless and Lambda because I thought it would make sense for a chatbot, but the more I add feature in my project, the more problems I get (database connection is really long...)

Comment: You appear to be asking "why is my code so slow?" without showing us any of your code.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're mostly stuck. Maybe one thing you could do is try to make as many async calls as you can in parallel. It sounds like your flow is currently like this:

```
Event -> Dialogflow -> Messenger -> Messenger -> Finish
```

You could try and combine some of these calls and execute them in parallel:

```
Event -> Messenger -> Messenger -> Finish
      -> Dialogflow ->
```

Answer (score 0):

AWS Lambda may not be cost-effective in cases like that.

To optimize the cost you can consider:

1. Use async requests as much as possible.
2. Reduce the lambda's memory size. It will also make it run slower, so the optimized value can be usually found by trial and error. In your case, reducing it to the minimum possible may be of best fit. Check [this](https://epsagon.com/blog/how-to-make-lambda-faster-memory-performance-benchmark/) example.
3. Batch multiple events to a single invocation, and process them asynchronously. For example, in your case, you can aggregate multiple interactions of different users using services such as Kinesis Data Streams and SQS, handle them in the same invocation, and send the separate response for each one of them.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite old but may still be relevant.  One solution may be as follows:-

1. Create a Request SQS Queue and a Response SQS queue
2. Have a Request Lambda that
   a) Enqueues the Request to the SQS Request Queue (with a TicketId :: Guid)
   b) Makes an Async request to the Lambda function (no particular parameters)
   c) Returns the TicketID to the caller
3. The Lambda function starts up and on the first (init) request does a no-wait request on the SQS request queue
   a) If there is a message, then it processes the messages as an async Task in the background
   b) while the api request is being processed, then the Lambda function makes a long poll call to the Request Queue to look for more Requests to process. The long poll time should be about as long as the max api call time
   c) If it gets another SQS Request then it processes it asyncly in the background and repeats looking for more
   d) It continues processing SQS Requests until either it gets to about 10 or 12 minutes of processing (within the 15 minute max time.  i.e. end of Lambda lifetime) OR it does not get another SQS Request within the long poll time (no more work).  It will then complete its current requests and the Lambda function instance will end.
4. New Requests will Enqueue and call the Lambda function.  As the first instance is busy polling for new requests then this new instance will typically not see the new SQS request and so will just end.  So just waste say 100ms instead of say 10s.  The first instance is now being better utilized as is handling many requests in parallel.

If the first instance runs out of capacity then the next instance will find the enqueued Request and begin processing it and so hence scale-out.

If the first instance ends due to no-work or max-time, then the next instance will take over seamlessly.

When an api gets its response, then this is published to the SQS Response queue with a header of the TicketID.

The caller after making a request will do along poll on the SQS Response queue with the TicketID to get the response.

So no special locking or database necessary. Full scale out and no additional latency issues.